# Join a same table using key and values to get data in one row

Tags: mysql, join, mysql-error-1064

This is my table structure,

i wabt to combine the same table with its key values like prop_key ='color'

```
id    journal_id     property     prop_key       old_value                        value
405   252             attr         color         1                                 0
372   252             attr       updated_at      2017-03-18 03:43:34 UTC     2017-03-18 03:43:34 UTC
402   252             attr       sprint_id       5                                 0
```

I want the result in this form.

```
id           color       sprint_id           start_date
372           2           5               2017-03-18 03:43:34 UTC
```

I try the following

```
select t.id,
       max(case when a.prop_key='color' then a.value end) attr_val1,
       max(case when a.prop_key='sprint_id' then a.value end) attr_val2,
       max(case when a.prop_key='updated_at' then a.value end) attr_val3
from journal_details t
left join journal_details a on t.id = a.id
where t.journal_id=242 
group by t.id

Select 
    journal_details.id,  
    a1.value as color,
    a2.value as sprint_id,
    a3.value as start_date
from journal_details
    left join (select * from journal_details where prop_key='color') a1 on journal_details.id=a1.id
    left join (select * from journal_details where prop_key='sprint_id') a2 on journal_details.id=a2.id
    left join (select * from journal_details where prop_key='start_date') a3 on journal_details.id=a3.id
    where journal_details.journal_id=242
```

But i didnot get satisfactory result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a self join.

Try this:

```
select min(id),
    max(case when prop_key = 'color' then value end) attr_val1,
    max(case when prop_key = 'sprint_id' then value end) attr_val2,
    max(case when prop_key = 'updated_at' then value end) attr_val3
from journal_details
where journal_id = 242
```

Comment: But it give the 5 row with different value like this

http://prntscr.com/eldkp5

but i want the one row with all result

Comment: @Navjot - Do you want to group on journal_id column? min(id) perhaps? What is the value in id column in your result? In your question, you showed 372 in expected output, but where did it come from? You input data doesnt have it

Comment: @NavjotSingh - Updated the answer. Try now